# Terraform provider resource dependencies

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If you have e.g. an AWS instance with an elastic IP, Terraform will wait for the EC2 instance to be ready before creating the IP.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example_a" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = aws_instance.example_a.id
}
```

As the Provider developer, how can I implement this sort of functionality in the Terraform plugins framework? For simplicity, let's assume that `aws_instance` has a status field that will be 'pending' initially, but 'created' once ready. I want to wait to create the IP until the `aws_instance` is in 'created' state.

Comment: Please see discussion on Martin's answer below. I would like an explanation of how this is supposed to work and the "Hashicups" tutorials most certainly do not provide one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called Cross Resource Attribute Reference and Terraform implements the behavior you've described automatically if you use reference to a resource attribute in another resource attribute's value.

Terraform can see that the `resource "aws_eip" "ip"` block contains a reference to `aws_instance.example_a`, and so it automatically infers that `aws_eip.ip` cannot be modified until `aws_instance.example_a` has been modified.

The provider is not aware of this and only sees the final values provided by Terraform after evaluting the expressions.

As a provider developer, your responsibility is only to wait to return from the "create" operation until the object is ready to use. In the case of `aws_instance`, the provider achieves that by politely polling the EC2 API to wait for the status to change, and returning only once it's reached a suitable terminal status.

Comment: So, the provider should not call resp.State.Set(ctx, plan) until the object is in the "created" state? Until then I should loop in the Create(), polling the API waiting for the right state, and not return anything?

So in the Hashicups tutorial here, https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/providers-plugin-framework/providers-plugin-framework-resource-create#implement-create-functionality it would call CreateOrder() but then it would call GetOrder(ID) in a loop?

Also do I need to protect against reentry? (Check for order already exists) in case the process gets killed?

Comment: I must admit that I don't recall off the top of my head the full details of how the plugin framework models this, but I think setting a new state immediately after you create the new object will be the best behavior, since then if the operation gets cancelled your provider can still return a partially-created object. You might choose to include the status as one of the attributes of your resource type so that when you initially write the state it will be clearly marked as not yet fully created while still being tracked as existing in the Terraform state.

Comment: The most important thing is that once an object exists in the remote system you _must not_ return a null state, because if you do that then Terraform will not "remember" that the object exists and so will propose to create it again in the next plan.